# DataGridView AutoSize

Tags: .net, winforms

Is there any way to make DataGridView fit the width and height of colums/rows? I have found the solution which requires manual calulation: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/datagrid/article.php/c9603 Does DataGridView really not support this feature?

Comment: this may help but probably not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691433/resize-datagridview-width-to-fit-columns

Comment: on the other hand, this e.g. my answer to this, might help a bit more in that I know it works for me to autosize the datagridview width to include the size of all columns http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424514/datagridview-autosize/6424721#comment62501943_6424721

Answer (score 8):

if you want to make all the columns to resize automatically according to data:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
}
```

Comment: I want a contrary thing: to autosize control to current columns size

Comment: you don't want columns to autosize according to their content??

Comment: No. I want to keep columns as they are.

Comment: ok then, try: dataGridView.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;

Comment: Tried to add a `VB.NET` snippet here, then realized it should just be an extra answer.

Comment: @twip: not much to translate here.

Comment: don't ask him to tell you if it works. Test it  properly yourself

Comment: can do `dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells; ` and 
`dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;`

Answer (score 6):

This is a pretty old question that has been misunderstood IMHO. What Idsa wants to achieve is to make the actual `AutoSize` winforms feature to work with the DataGridView. The property exists but it has no effect.

This means the DataGridView has to fit *around* its content, not its content has to fit *inside* the DataGridView.

There are a lot of things to think about to achieve a AutoSize implementation. The DataGridView size depends on a lot of criterias:

- Border size
- Padding
- Cell Delimiter size
- Row Header height
- Column header width
- How the DataGridView is populated (DataBound or manually)
- ... a lot more

The best is to select a set of some criteria that fits your specific scenario, and write something that will compute the DataGridView size for you.

Here my specific scenario as an example:

- my grid is data bound. So its size is supposed to change each time a DataBinding operation is complete. This is the condition that trigger a recalculation of the DataGridView size. So I hook it to the `DataBindingComplete` event.
- my grid is not supposed to display scrollbars. So I set the `Scrollbars` property to None.
- My row and columns autosize mode are set to AllCells.
- Rows and Columns header are not visible. If they were, their sizes has to be included in the calculation.

The extension below method fits my needs. It is very simple because my grids are very simple. You will probably have to tweak it a bit to make it work as you wish, and a *lot* to make it work for every DataGridView scenarios.

```
public static void HandleAutoSize(this DataGridView dgv)
{
    dgv.DataBindingComplete += (s, e) =>
    {
        var dg = (DataGridView)s;
        var width = dg.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.None);
        var height = dg.Rows.GetRowsHeight(DataGridViewElementStates.None);

        dg.ClientSize = new Size(width, height);
    };
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. But then the debugger says there are no columns, despite showing a DataSource that has content from which it should autogenerated columns and rows.

Comment: Works great. I used the RowHeightChanged & ColumnWidthChanged events, but used `BeginInvoke(Sub() AdjustDGVSize())` in those to wait for the sizes to actually change. Where `AdjustDGVSize()` is the sub that sets the dgv clientsize. I also set the width of non-visible columns to 6 px.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [AutoSizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode.aspx) and [Fill Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171605.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This `VB.NET` translation worked for me:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dataGridView.ColumnCount - 1
    dataGridView.Columns(i).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

The thread is quite old, but in case someone still needs it now he can use
grid.AutoResizeColumns()
works fine with me

Answer (score 0):

## The Real Answer

I wrote this code to calculate the exact size of the grid using pixel color and comparing it the background. It works great for me. It causes some flicker if you use autosize on the containing form, you must disable autosize or modify the code to manually set the size on the containing form. But, without autosize on the parent control it works perfectly.

```
 private void gridViewAutoSize(DataGridView dgv)
        {

            Bitmap dgvBmp = new Bitmap(dgv.Width,dgv.Height);
            dynRecDataGridView.DrawToBitmap(dgvBmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, dgv.Width, dgv.Height));

            int x = dgv.Width-1;
            int y = dgv.Height-1;
            int halfHeaderW = dgv.RowHeadersWidth / 2;
            int halfHeaderH = dgv.ColumnHeadersHeight / 2;
            int borderX = 0;
            int borderY = 0;
            const int widthLimit = 800;
            const int heightLimit = 350;

            while (x == dgv.Width - 1)
            {
                borderX = 0;
                while (x >= 0 && dgvBmp.GetPixel(x, halfHeaderH).ToArgb() != dgv.BackgroundColor.ToArgb())
                {
                    borderX++;
                    x--;
                }
                if (x < 0)
                {
                    if(dgv.Width-1 <= widthLimit)
                    {
                        dgv.Width += 100;
                        dgvBmp = new Bitmap(dgv.Width, dgv.Height);
                        dynRecDataGridView.DrawToBitmap(dgvBmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, dgv.Width, dgv.Height));

                        x = dgv.Width - 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        x = widthLimit;
                        borderX = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (x > widthLimit)
            {
                x = widthLimit;
                borderX = 0;
            }
            else if(x < widthLimit)
            {
                while (dgvBmp.GetPixel(x, halfHeaderH).ToArgb() == dgv.BackgroundColor.ToArgb())
                {
                    x--;
                }
            }
            while (y == dgv.Height - 1)
            {
                borderY = 0;
                while (y >= 0  && dgvBmp.GetPixel(halfHeaderW, y).ToArgb() != dgv.BackgroundColor.ToArgb())
                {
                    borderY++;
                    y--;
                }
                if (y < 0)
                {
                    if (dgv.Height-1 <= heightLimit)
                    {
                        dgv.Height += 100;
                        dgvBmp = new Bitmap(dgv.Width, dgv.Height);
                        dynRecDataGridView.DrawToBitmap(dgvBmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, dgv.Width, dgv.Height));

                        y = dgv.Height - 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        y = heightLimit;
                        borderY = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (y > heightLimit)
            {
                y = heightLimit;
                borderY = 0;
            }
            else if (y < heightLimit)
            {
                while (dgvBmp.GetPixel(halfHeaderW, y).ToArgb() == dgv.BackgroundColor.ToArgb())
                {
                    y--;
                }
            }

            dgv.Size = new Size(x+borderX+1, y+borderY+1);

        }
```

Comment: Where and how do you define `dynRecDataGridView` on line #5?

Comment: It is a `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` class, placed onto a form via the IDE UI toolbox and named 'dynRecDataGridView', https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score -1):

you can just change dataGridView properties To

```
dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```